# How to append zero to dd/mm/yyyy c# like 01/01/2017

Tags: c#

I am looking to convert something like this: example: 01/01/2017 is what i found in SQL server  ,But when i try to read the values which is in list result is 1/1/2017, how do i append zeros to it like 01/01/2017?

Comment: The zero only matters if you are storing dates as a string.  Dates are simply a value and the zeds wont matter except when displaying

Comment: You're prepending, not appending. You might be looking for [`DateTime.ToString(format)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tostring?view=netframework-4.8#System_DateTime_ToString_System_String_), but it really depends on exactly what you are trying to do with the date. Please provide more detail. EDIT: Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: @Ňɏssa Pøngjǣrdenlarp yes i am storing it in string and trying to enter it in my app , it accepts date in this format 01/01/2017 but i/p i am getting is 1/1/2017

Comment: *"But when I try to read the values which is in list result is 1/1/2017"*. Please show the code you're referring to here. Assuming you're storing the value in a `DateTime` type, then the way it's appears in UI is based on the format string used to show it, but the value itself is the same in either case. You can format it the way you want using a [standard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings) or [custom](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings) format string.

Comment: If you store dates as dates, you would not have this problem.

Answer (score 2):

`DateTime` doesn't have a format. It simply stores `Year`, `Month` etc data in its properties. So when you read data from the database and convert it into a `DateTime` object, it will simply store that relevant data.

```
var dateFromDB = "01/01/2017";
DateTime.TryParse(dateFromDB, out DateTime dt);
```

So your 'formatted' data will no longer be available. But whenever you want to use this `DateTime`, you can convert it to a string using the appropriate format. So, to get your `01/01/2017`, you'd have to use the format `MM/dd/yyyy` (assuming this is a USA format where month/day/year is the order).

So,

```
var formattedDate = dt.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

will give you a string in your expected format.

You can find a list of format specifiers [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings).

Answer (score 0):

select convert(varchar, CAST('1/1/2017' AS date), 103)

Output
01/01/2017